# bubble sort implementation on linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, bubble-sort

I got an error in LinkList.java, in "curr.names.length()-1". The .length comes as an error. How do I fix this? Still new here and I don't really understand Java well. Just thought I'd give it a try. this are the code I got:

*SinglyNode.java*

```
public class SinglyNode
{
public Object names;
public SinglyNode next;

public SinglyNode (Object name1)
{
    names = name1;
    next = null;
}

public void setNext(SinglyNode next1)
{
    next = next1;
}

Object getObject()
{
    return names;
}

SinglyNode getNext()
{
    return next;
}

void displayLink()
{
    System.out.print("{" + names + "}");
}
}
```

*LinkList.java* The error is in here

```
public class LinkList
{
SinglyNode first;
SinglyNode last;

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (first == null);
}

void insertFirst(Object name1)
{
    SinglyNode newNode1 = new SinglyNode(name1);
    newNode1.next = first;
    first = newNode1;
}

void display()
{
    SinglyNode current = first;
    while(current != null)
    {
        current.displayLink(); // print data
        current = current.next; // move to next link
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}

public void bubbleSort()
{
    int length = 0;
    SinglyNode hold = first;
    while(true)
    {
        if(hold == last)
        {
            break;
        }
        hold = hold.next;
        length++;
    }
    while(true)
    {
        if(length == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        int i = 0;

        SinglyNode curr = first;
        while(true)
        {
            if(i == length)
            {
                break;
            }
            if( curr.names.charAt(curr.names.length()-1) > 
                    curr.next.names.charAt(curr.next.names.length()-1))
            {
                swap(curr);
            }
            curr = curr.next;
            i++;
        }
        length--;
    }
}

private void swap(SinglyNode node)
{
    Object temp = node.names;
    node.names = node.next.names;
    node.next.names = temp;
}
}
```

And here's the main class
*MainApp.java*

```
ppublic class MainApp
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
    LinkList list = new LinkList();

    list.insertFirst("Squirtle");
    list.insertFirst("Bulbasaur");
    list.insertFirst("Charmander");
    list.insertFirst("Pichu");
    list.insertFirst("Ghastly");
    list.insertFirst("Mewtwo");
    list.insertFirst("Dialga"); 

    System.out.println("LIST: ");
    list.display();

    System.out.println("BUBBLE SORT: ");
    list.bubbleSort();
    list.display();

}
}
```

Comment: What is the error?  It looks like the `names` member is of type `Object`.  Does `Object` even have a member called `length()`?  I don't think it does: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object` does not have a `length()` method - you can only call `.length()` on a class with the appropriate method signature. Did you intend this to be a `String`?  If so, change your code to `public String names`, `public SinglyNode(String name1)`, and `String getObject()` (or `String getName()` or `String getString()`)

Comment: I did, but then "node.next.names = temp;" in LinkList gets an error

Comment: Change `Object temp` to `String temp`.  Change all of your Objects to Strings.  You can't assign an Object to a String without first casting it, e.g. `node.next.names = (String)temp`; however, in this case there's no reason for temp to be an Object in the first place.

Comment: Okay, I got it. But then I get this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" it says in "if(curr.names.charAt(curr.names.length()-1) >" line

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: A debugger will give you the same result, but it will let you step through the program to figure out why you're getting an error. If you're not using an IDE, then download [eclipse] (http://www.eclipse.org/) for Java and read a tutorial on how to debug with it.